# handle JSON object in Presto/Trino

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have JSON data like this in one of my columns
`{"foo": 1, "bar": 2} {"foo": 1}`
and I would like to run a query that returns the only apoint keys ["foo"]

`{"foo":1}`

Comment: what is the data type of your JSON column? select typeof(<json column>) from table will give you this and you can update the same in your question.

Comment: my data type is row(provinceId bigint, province varchar, cityId bigint, city varchar, countyId bigint, county varchar, address varchar)
and i would like only keep provinceId and cityId
after that my real idea is get the result to group by cityId

Comment: if column is address:{"provinceId":100, "cityId":110, contryId:111} 
i want group by provinceId and cityId and it result is address:{"provinceId":100, "cityId":110}

Comment: Please update your question actual JSON matching the schema you shared and DDL used to create table to help you better

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> my data type is `row(provinceId bigint, province varchar, cityId bigint, city varchar, countyId bigint, county varchar, address varchar)`

then your data is not json, it is of [`ROW`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row) type, which allows to access fields by name, i.e. in your case something like:

```sql
select my_column.provinceId, my_column.cityId
from my_table
```

Comment: thank you , my question is not clear , the row type have many keys ,  and i want to keep appoint keys

Comment: @dapisces you can create a new row, having only needed keys by selecting only them.